# Making Gridview Column full of URLs Clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table in my database which contains URL addresses. So I have  a "Sport" column and then a "links" which has all the URLs from articles on  the internet.

I am displaying this on a gridview but I want to be able to click on the URL in the "Links" column.
This is my markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sport" HeaderText="Sport" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Link" HeaderText="Link" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: use template field that will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<asp:TemplateField>` instead of `<asp:BoundField>` for link :

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <HeaderTemplate>
            Link
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
           NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Link") %>'
           Text="Your text">
       </asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```